# making a textbox visible depending on Dropdown list selection

Tags: jquery, .net

I have a dropdownlist with options and the last option is Other. If the user selects Other I have to make a text box visible.

I did it using asp.net and made the autopostback=true for ddlchanged event. When I follow this when ever the user selects other the page flickers and going to the top.

somebody told me that I can use jquery to do it with out loading the page again. can you tell me how?
Also it should also check the required field validation.

Answer (score 3):

Using jquery it will looks like:

```
$('#dropdown').change(function() {
   if ($(this).val() == 'Other')
    {
      $('#textbox').show();
    }
    else
    {
      $('#textbox').hide();
    }

});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/8Ct5r/

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ddlColl').change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == 'Other') {
                    //                $('#txtOther').show();
                    $('#txtOther').css('display', 'inline');
                }
                else {
                    //                $('#txtOther').hide();

                    $('#txtOther').css('display', 'block');
                }

            });

    });
    </script>

Comment: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtOther" style="display:none;" > </asp:TextBox>

Comment: What it should do? :) The only thing I noticed that this is server controls and in javascript ID of the control can be different, like `ctrl01_txtOther`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#dropdownID').change(function () {
        var dropdownValue = $('#dropdownID').val();

        if (dropdownValue == 71) {
            $('#TextboxID').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#TextboxID').hide();
        }
    })
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.